# Pythonic way to store and reference a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a "World" class, it has several class methods involving generating different types of features, Id like to store references to these methods in a dictionary where they are the value and the key is the "type" of thing they are generating, a river, castle or road or example, what is the most Pythonic way to do this? I could create a dictionary in the "World" class but I'm not sure if storing it there is the best idea, I was thinking it might be better store this dictionary outside the "World" class but then how do I reference the method? I could store the methods as strings, "generate_site_river" for example, then use attrget() to get the method but I'm not sure this is a good idea, what is the most Pythonic thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the references to the methods themselves in the dict - not as strings.

Here's an example:

```
class World(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def create_river(self):
        print(f"Created a river in {self._name}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = World('Earth')

    method_dict = {
        'river': w.create_river
    }

    method_dict.get('river')()
```

Output:

```
Created a river in Earth
```